# Extra data usage V having a local DB(cache) in an app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Working on an app where all the contents/data for it will be coming via JSON and occasionally i will display a HTML page.

The client is suggesting that maybe we should have some local database(MYSQL Lite) to cache the JSON data returned so we use less of the users data(if there search for the same item again) allowance and because it maybe slightly faster.

Are these good enough reasons for adding the extra complexity and potential problems of having a local DB on the phone?

I didn't think from my experience that the phone was particularly slow or that JSON or HTML were data heavy in there data usage. I'd prefer having a thin client.

Facebook/Twitter/etc work with very little problems using JSON and Html.

Would I be wrong to try steer away from the local DB idea?
Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caching url request results can improve your application's latency over a slow connexion. You could use CoreData to manually manage a cache (key:url, value:request's answer)

Another more elegant solution would be (if you have write access to the webservices) to implement server-side the "if-modified-since" header so that your request data received would be kept at a minimum level.